# SpannableString on canvas is shifting unexpectedly - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, canvas

I'm trying to display the text on custom ImageView using canvas.
This is my TextPaint:

```
    mPaint = new TextPaint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    mPaint.setTypeface(tf);
    mPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setTextSize(mSize);
```

User enters his text in EditText which is converted into String(**sText**) and then into SpannableString(**ssText**). That SpannableString is being displayed on the canvas.
This is my onDraw:

```
int x = this.getWidth() / 2, y = 10;    
Editable.Factory fac = Editable.Factory.getInstance();
Editable edit = fac.newEditable(ssText);
DynamicLayout layout = new DynamicLayout(edit, mPaint, (x * 2), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1, 0, false);
canvas.translate(x, y);
layout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Now, I'm taking some strings(**mText**) as input (one string in one line) from user in EditText of which I have to change color in the already displayed SpannableString(**ssText**) on the canvas.

```
for (String line : mText.split("\n")) {                   // one string one line
    if (sText.matches(".*\\b" + line + "\\b.*")) {
            int len = line.length();
                  // get the starting index of String line in sText
            for (int i = -1; (i = sText.indexOf(mText, i + 1)) != -1;) {
                  // change the color of required text in ssText                        
                ssText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(r_deep, g_deep, b_deep)), i, (i + len), 0);
            }
    }
}
```

After changing the color of **ssText** as above I again call onDraw on the click of ChangeColor button to diaplay it back on the canvas. But, here what I see is that the position of the **ssText** on canvas is irregular.
I see this before the click of ChangeColor button: [image]

And this is after click of ChangeColor button:[image]

If the problem is in translate of canvas the I'm also using canvas.restore();

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help!

Comment: The obvious question is. Where is the `canvas.save()` call? As `canvas.restore()` has nothing to restore from though it should throw an error so you may have a save just at the wrong place maybe?. The `canvas.save()` should go just before the translate.

Comment: @Blindman67 I tried using `canvas.save();` right before `canvas.translate(x, y);` but it did not work out. Output is still the same.